# Can users change questions (after a year+) making previous answers invalid/bad?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I remember responding with an answer to a user's questions many months ago. I received many +1s for the answer. Then suddenly I receive bad reps and a high-rank user commented to me that I did not address the original question.

When I re-read the OPs question I saw that my answer had little to do with its context.

I can't remember what the exact question was the day I responded, and that is why I am so perplexed. But is it possible for a user to change or remove parts of a question making *some* previous answers invalid?

Possibly someone else later edited it and removed something?

*Could a moderator (or myself) see the question as it was the at moment I responded to it?*

I just want to understand if I made a mistake or not and move on. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the question, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072537/how-to-catch-error-1062-duplicate-entry-independent-from-used-database-engine

Comment: That's the one, I am not sure if I was being helpful or way off topic.. Sry.

Comment: I am not an expert in that area, but from what I can see question was not edited in way that would invalidate your answer. Expert that commented is right, you missed the point of the question. why other have upvoted... I don't know.

Comment: @Dalija, I agree, I don't know either, lol, It was when I was first starting getting into programing and Python, I was very new at all this stuff and probably thought I was helping. Sorry for that.

Comment: I deleted that answer just now because it was not helping the community. Sorry for any inconvenience it may have caused.

Comment: @Logic1 Congrats on your new badge!

Comment: No need to apologize... This things happen. I have also deleted answer with 6 up votes where I missed the point of the question. I know a guy that deleted answer with more than 70 upvotes because it turned out to be wrong (it was difficult issue, so on the surface it seemed that his answer was good one and it took few years until someone figured the real issue behind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the question's edit history in several ways. The easiest (now) is to click the "timeline" icon (under the "favourite" star, under the vote score). Also, if the question *has* been edited, there will be a clear "edited (by...)" under it, near the centre-screen. You can click on that to see the edit history. You need 2,000 rep (IIRC) to actually make a rollback, but that could be an option. Or just leave a comment, saying that it's been edited badly, and another user could do the rollback for you.

However, it is, IMHO, **very bad form** to edit a question in such a way that any already-posted answer(s) is/are invalidated by that edit.

If you, or somebody else, does the rollback to the 'original' version, then the OP (or somebody else) undoes that rollback, you should raise a moderator flag, and explain what's going on - the question may then be *locked* into its appropriate version.

Comment: I would have to add that, although I'm no expert in the subject matter of the question, it doesn't appear that the edit has invalidated your answer. The commentator (on your answer) has possibly made a valid observation.